# Green tomato soup calls for creme fraiche. I cannot have creme fraiche. If I add heavy creme will it be ok?

Tags: substitutions, soup

I want to make green tomato soup but the recipe I have calls for creme fraiche. I cannot get creme fraiche. Will using heavy cream as a substitute smooth out the sourness of the green tomatoes and still be pleasant tasting? I prefer a little sweet to tart tasting anyway.

Comment: Can you wait 12 hours? You can make creme fraiche in that period of time. You could probably cheat and get a decent result in 8 hours.

Comment: Is the "cannot have" rooted in belief, diet, intolerance, not having any handy, or some other reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I look for in an alternative to crème fraîche?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/39859/what-should-i-look-for-in-an-alternative-to-cr%c3%a8me-fra%c3%aeche)

Answer (score 1):

If you add only heavy creme the final result will be more smooth and a little bit sweeter (even though green tomatoes are very sour to taste). If you have access to a white yogurt (non sweetened) or greek yogurt you can add that to the soup, maybe by adding it gradually and correcting with cream if the taste degenerates.

Comment: I'll try adding the heavy creme in a single bowl of soup and see where it goes also will try sour cream, maybe together both?  There is no way I can use yogurt, it is a no no for me.

Comment: i'm sorry for my mistake. yes, you can try in a small batch. after all, cooking is part following recipes to the single gram and part experiment!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make your own craime fraiche with heavy cream and a couple of tablespoons of live culture buttermilk.  Just let it sit in a warm place overnight and it will be ready the next morning.